# UITableView cell expand animation changes when top margin is not fully visible

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uikit

I try to make cells expand/collapse with drop-down like animation, so when table view recalculates height it moves **down** other cells **below** the one that was tapped,

but if the tapped cell top margin is not entirely visible, table view changes its height update behavior by moving all **above** cells **up**:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJbZK.jpg

Is there a way to make cells expand with top-to-bottom behavior always?
Reloading cells like this:

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:arrayToReload withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: What method are you using for your "Show more / less" function? Are you using auto-layout with UITableViewAutomaticDimension? Or are you returning specific values in `heightForRowAtIndexPath`? Or are you inserting / deleting rows?

Comment: Yes, UITableViewAutomaticDimension with begin/end updates and row reload as shown above. I also return precalculated cell heights in estimatedHeightForRow. Inserting/deleting rows instead of reload doesn't seem to make a difference

Comment: OK - depending on exactly how you are changing the cell content constraints for show/hide, you may get better results *without* the call to `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths`... Are you manipulating those values *inside* the cell or in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: So I should configure cell height constraints inside update brackets instead  of reload, that will require precise height calculation tho, before I was just returning height values that came from willDisplayCell (which is actually height of the previous time cell was displayed). I will try that.

Comment: You should be able to use constraints instead of calculating / assigning specific values. There are various approaches, and some implementations may work better in different ways, but you can see a couple different methods here: https://github.com/DonMag/DynamicCellHeight

Comment: ok I've managed to achieve the correct behavior without row reload, updating height constraints, thanks @DonMag. The only issue I have left is cell labels overlapping other cells while animating but that's another question.

Answer (score -1):

Just set the contentOffset based on selected row

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell * theCell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView     
                                              cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    CGPoint tableViewCenter = [tableView contentOffset];
    tableViewCenter.y += myTable.frame.size.height/2;

    [tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,theCell.center.y-65) animated:YES]; // need to customize the y offset 65 to your value
    // reload row here 
 }
```

Comment: I didn't quite get your code, but I've tried messing with animated table view offsets and scrollToRowAtIndexPath but it ended up conflicting with other animations such as row reload or constraints update